# Retrieve information from associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have 3 models:

```
class Brand 
  attr_accessible :obs, :site, :title
  has_many :equipments
end

class Equipment 
  attr_accessible :brand_id, :category_id, :lending_id 
  belongs_to :brand
  has_many :lendings  
end

class Lending  
 attr_accessible :equipment_id 

 belongs_to :equipment
end
```

I'm trying to show the brand of an associated equipament:
  Brand: <%= @lending.equipment.brand %>
  that command show this: Brand:0xab7f2c8

As you can see, there's no association between brand and lending models and for me its strange if i do that. I want to use the equipment/brand association to retrieve the :title information and show it on my lending view.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a delegate in `Lending`:

```
delegate :brand, :to => :equipment, allow_nil: true
```

Or you can setup a has-one-through association in `Lending`:

```
has_one :branch, :through => :equipment
```

Either way, you can now call `branch` directly from a `Lending` instance, and work on it (almost) as if it were a regular association.

Answer (score 1):

Use `delegate`

```
   class Lending  
     attr_accessible :equipment_id 

     belongs_to :equipment
     delegate :brand, :to => :equipment, :allow_nil => true
    end
```

now you can use

```
<%= @lending.brand.title%>
```